# Custom CloudFormation Resources in Terraform

Tags: aws-cloudformation, terraform

I'm trying out Terraform, and am in the process of translating one of my more interesting CloudFormation stacks to TF. Included as a key part of the stack is the following declaration that specifies a custom resource for the template - a Lambda that queries a list of AMIs and selects the latest one for the context, based on the description as a filter.

```
  LatestAMI:
    Type: Custom::LatestAMI
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:function:GetLatestAMI
      Description: ubuntu-16.04
```

I've looked around the Terraform docs, but I can't seem to find out how I can specify this resource. Is there a Terraform analog for custom resources in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CF codes you posted calls a lambda function to get the latest ami id (filter with `Description: ubuntu-16.04`. There is simpler way to do in terraform.

You need data source `aws_ami`

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html

Use this data source to get the ID of a registered AMI for use in other resources.

```
data "aws_ami" "latest_ami" {
  most_recent      = true
  executable_users = ["all"]

  filter {
    name   = "owner-alias"
    values = ["amazon"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["*ubuntu-16.04*"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! This definitely seems like it will work for this use case, however I have a few other templates with Custom Resources doing more complex things. It would be nice if there was a way to specify custom resources in general - this was just one example.

Comment: then you need to convert that lambda function `arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:XXXXXXX:function:GetLatestAMI` to terraform as well.